# How to handle optional login in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, roles, restful-authentication

I'm building a rails app where login is optional. In other words, many of the same actions/views/controllers/pages will work logged in or logged out. You simply get more functionality if you are logged in (like the app remembers what you've done).

I'm currently using restful_authentication and role_requirement, and wondering which level to use. I could add a new role "user" which all logged in users get, for example, and then `require_role "user"` and have view blocks using `@user.has_role?` ... or I could instead enhance the authentication side of things and do checks to see if the user is authenticated. Or I could do something else. Is there any standard way of handling this in rails?

Answer (score 1):

You would integrate your authentication gem with an authorization gem. To start off, I would recommend [cancan](http://github.com/ryanb/cancan) as it is very simple and straight forward.

If you are using cancan, you would define what user can/cannot do in models/ability.rb.

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      if user.admin?
        can :manage, :all
      else
        can :read, :all
      end
    end
end
```

Then in your view you can authorize the features based on user role:

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

If you are looking for more power, you might want to consider other authorization gem such as [declarative_authorization](http://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check for authorization for actions which allow all users.

If you have a default authorization in your ApplicationController, such as:

`before_filter :authorize`

Then either remove that entirely, and add it back in only for those actions that require authorization, or, in each controller you could disable it with:

`skip_before_filter :authorize, :only => [:action_method_name]`

You should have a simple method in your ApplicationController where you can pass in a role and get a true if the current user is authorized:

```
def authorized? role
  return true if current_user.roles.collect{|r| r.name.to_sym}.include(role.to_sym)
  false
end
```

Then you can check procedurally for whatever role you want in your actions.

Comment: I'd also like certain pages to show different views if the user is logged in vs. not logged in. Any advice on that?